# Can an exe be smaller than its largest declared buffer?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, buffer

The reason I'm asking:

```
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char file[512000];
    unsigned char key[512000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 512000; i++)
            file[i] = key[i];
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with cl.exe on windows I get an executable that is about 31kb in size. The buffers themselves are 500kb each. How does this make sense? Will part of it be allocated on the heap? If I initialized them with data then would the size be correct?

Comment: 31 KB seems an awful lot for this program. ;-)

Comment: 64KB should be enough for anyone...

Comment: Look, ma! I can produce useless comments.

Comment: @Brad: that's 640KB, and it's for any purpose *other than* factorizing large primes.

Comment: @goreSplatter, my comment was no more useless than yours, but if you really have a beef with it, I'll delete it.  @Steve, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @goreSplatter, well in that case I rescind the first half of my reply to the utterly useless comment that was a reply to the utterly useless comment that I was not aware of utterly uselessness until it has been pointed out about your reply to my reply to your reply to the newly noticed utterly useless comment.  I will now go to the bar...  Good day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, the buffers will be allocated on the program's [stack space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) at runtime.  There's no need for them to be statically built into the `exe` file.

Comment: I think all stack allocations should happen only in runtime (I'm not talking about constants)

Comment: @Elalfer, sure - that's because the stack only comes into existence at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that you're declaring *variables* (rather, blocks of them), not defining data that has to be stored in the application. All you're storing on the hard drive is a series of *instructions*, not the buffers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Those arrays are allocated on the stack, just like all auto variables. It would be senseless to have a long string of zeroes in the binary just to signify their size. If you were to define the entire contents of the arrays in your code, then yes, the binary size would be close to the sum of the array sizes and the size of the compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

The arrays are allocated, initialized and used during runtime **in the working memory**. They are not saved in the .exe or in any file (save virtual memory or swap files).

Comment: In fact thay are `auto` variables, so that are only allocated, not initialised.  That would be true if they were declared `static`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I was just giving a more general example that goes beyond the actual snippet (I didn't completely read it).

Answer (score 0):

Only non-zero initialisation data would be required to built into the executable binary; these are unitialised arrays.